# Libgtksourceview-2.0dev and Ocaml/Opam/Ocaml-Top on Debian 11

Tags: debian, ocaml, opam

Good evening,
After the release of Debian 11 I tried to install Ocaml-Top on it.
The problem relies on the following library, on which Ocaml-Top depends:
libgtksourceview-2.0dev .
On Debian 11 it is not supported anymore, so, after installing Ocaml and Opam, with all their dependencies, is not possible to use Opam to install Ocaml-Top.
Does anyone have the same issue?
How did you solved it?

Thank you in advance

Alex

Comment: Debian 9 has libgtksourceview-3.0! . ..... So either use the year 2014 `libgtksourceview2.0-dev_2.10.5-2_amd64.deb` + `libgtksourceview2.0-0_2.10.5-2_amd64.deb` .... or build `gtksourceview2_2.10.5.orig.tar.bz2`  from source  http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/pool/main/g/gtksourceview2/

Answer (score 0):

Debian 9 and Debian 10 both supported libgtksourceview2.0, so they had libgtksourceview2.0-dev in their repositories.

Since the list of dependencies were too long (for anyone having a real life) I decided to try a dirty attempt:
enabling Debian 10 repositories together with the 11 ones.
In a Virtual Machine, obviously.
It worked...

Happy for the result, I formatted my laptop and tried the same, for the real install.
It didn't work...
Seems that opam hates me...